# Finding a value for when Fahrenheit and Celsius are equal when given an equation linking them together

Tags: linear-algebra

Equation linking Fahrenheit and Celcius is $F=1.8C+32$

For what value is the temperature in Fahrenheit the same temperature in Celcius?

I've got a value of -40 using trial and error but I would like to have a more methodological way of working it out.

Comment: Solve for $x$ in $x=1.8x+32$

Comment: @Dunham omg thanku so much I failed to spot that!